# Potential Race Condition? I can't seem to find the problem here

Tags: python, multithreading

I am facing this problem in my script that uses threads. All of my expected results are there in the `print(abcd_logging)`.

However in `print(results)` there are a few missing data.

This is the code (The code might not compile because I made this as a representation of the actual code, but hopefully enough to paint the picture of the problem):

```
def task(i):
    abcd_logging = get_results(i)
    print(abcd_logging)
    return [n for n in get_results(i)]

results = []

futures = [executor.submit(task, i) for i in range(5000)]

for future in as_completed(futures):
        # retrieve the result
        result = future.result()
        results = results + result

print(results)
```

I assume there might be no other cause apart from Race condition

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: No, it's not enough to paint a picture of the problem. However, try `results.extend(result)` instead...?

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Apologies, I will edit the code to make the question clearer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: It might help if you rewrite that code so that it demonstrates your problem by failing an assert.  For instance, if you are telling us that there are missing items in 'results', then adding the code `assert len(results) == 5000` would be a way of failing in the case where results is other than 5000 elements. If you provide code in that form, you will not only help us check it, you might also fix the problem yourself in the process.  And please provide a full example, in your code we have no definition of 'get_results' and 'executor'.  I tried your code and saw no problems.